# Toggling hide/show in vue-cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have two components.
The first one is a header with an image.
The second one is a div with a list.
I need to click the image (in the first component) to show the list (second component) and click it again to hide it.
The div should replace all the content below the image (so I can click the image again to hide the div and show default content).
Please see the picture for details. Links to the code below.

[image: the picture]

The code:

1. Component with the picture which has to work with v-on:click
   https://github.com/Mike-OxHuge/shop-on-vue-cli/blob/master/src/components/main-header.vue
2. Component which supposed to appear/disappear when I click the picture in component 1
   https://github.com/Mike-OxHuge/shop-on-vue-cli/blob/master/src/components/menu.vue
3. Component which supposed to be shown by default, but disappear or being covered by component 2
   https://github.com/Mike-OxHuge/shop-on-vue-cli/blob/master/src/components/main-page-content.vue
4. App.vue
   https://github.com/Mike-OxHuge/shop-on-vue-cli/blob/master/src/App.vue
5. And main.js
   https://github.com/Mike-OxHuge/shop-on-vue-cli/blob/master/src/main.js

Comment: can you share some part of the code for more clarity?

Comment: Don't know which parts of code would help... So I added links to github.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on on click handlers in Vue, and binding the v-dom to data variables.

Here's an example:

JS:

```
var vue = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: {
  isShowing:false,
  }
})
```

v-dom:

```
<div id="app">
   <iframe v-show="isShowing" src="http://www.weather.gov/" 
        frameborder="0"
        ></iframe>
  <button @click="isShowing ^= true">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/michael_coder/pen/WReNNm

Comment: yes it works, thank you. But I need to hide/show another component. Instead of the third component. I think it's about import/export... I am a beginner in these things.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    Hide: false
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button v-on:click="Hide = !Hide">Click Me</button>
<div v-if="!Hide"><ul><li>One</li>
<li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>four</li><li>five</li><li>six</li></ul></div>
</div>
```